# MySQL Partition by Month not working

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I create a table by

```
CREATE TABLE `part_tab` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `use_time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
PARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(use_time)) PARTITIONS 12;
```

then I use EXPLAIN PARTIONS syntax, but it seems that MySQL didn't use that partition, it still scans the whole table:

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from part_tab where use_time < '2013-02-01' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: part_tab
   partitions: p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 12
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if I change the where condition to equal，the partition is used:

```
 mysql> explain partitions select * from part_tab where use_time = '2013-02-01' \G
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: part_tab
   partitions: p2
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think it is because you partition by `HASH(MONTH(use_time))` yet search using a 'raw' date value.. I'd say try partitioning by `HASH(\`use_time\`)`

Comment: But what i want to do is partition by month...

Comment: Do you want to do that based on some logical reason? Or just because you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select *
from part_tab
where use_time = '2013-02-01';
```

Your partition statement is:

```
PARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(use_time)) PARTITIONS 12;
```

What you are trying to do is called "partition pruning".  According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-pruning.html),

> Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a DATE or
>   DATETIME column when the partitioning expression uses the YEAR() or
>   TO_DAYS() function. In addition, in MySQL 5.7, pruning can be applied
>   for such tables when the partitioning expression uses the TO_SECONDS()
>   function.

I don't believe there is any way to do partition pruning directly on `MONTH()` instead of `YEAR()`.  You can rewrite your query as:

```
select *
from part_tab
where month(use_time) = 1;
```

However, I suspect that range partitioning on the date is a better solution.